# Number of pixels scrolled by when clicking on a scrollbar's arrow in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Is there a way to control the number of pixels the contents of an HTML element are scrolled by when the user clicks on the scrollbar's arrows (rather than sliding the scrollbar itself), maybe using CSS and Javascript?

Comment: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

Comment: You could track the top of the window relative to the top of the document. I don't have the code for it right now, but it's a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Use this. http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/mousewheel

Load JQuery and the Mouse Wheel plugin.

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>
```

Then do something like this:

```
$(function() {

   $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

  this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);

  event.preventDefault();

   });

});
```

*Please realize that I said "something like this", you will need to modify and/or add code to that to get your desired results, this is just getting you on the right path*

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it though the fixed scroll amount is for both the arrows and the bar. If you load this in the browser you will see that the left div only scrolls by a fixed number of pixels and so the black bars are always aligned. The right div has normal scrolling and the black bars get misaligned.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .scroller { 
            height: 220px;
            width: 120px;
            overflow: auto;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 40px;
        }

        .item {
            height: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function init() {
            var scroller1 = document.getElementById("scroller1");
            initScroller(scroller1);
            scroller1.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

            var scroller2 = document.getElementById("scroller2");
            initScroller(scroller2);
        }

        function initScroller(node) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
                var elem = document.createElement("div");
                elem.setAttribute("class", "item");
                elem.innerHTML = "item " + i;
                node.appendChild(elem);
            }
        }

        var lastScroll = 0;
        var deltaPerScroll = 22;
        function onScroll(evt) {
            var node = document.getElementById("scroller1");
            if (node.scrollTop != lastScroll) {
                var delta = node.scrollTop < lastScroll ? -deltaPerScroll : deltaPerScroll;
                node.scrollTop = lastScroll + delta;
            }
            lastScroll = node.scrollTop;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <div id="scroller1" class="scroller"></div>
    <div id="scroller2" class="scroller"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

That said, I'm fairly sure a single click of the scroll arrow will fire a single `onscroll` event, so you could potentially limit the amount of scrolling allowed per `onscroll` event fired, but that means you can only decrease the default amount, you can't increase it.

Comment: No, it fires many times because you need a smooth transition.